# Suggestions for WYSIWYG editor for web-based data-entry screens?

Tags: html, forms, user-interface

I don't have a lot of experience developing web-based data entry software, but comparative to Oracle Forms, Visual Studio, and various 4th generation languages, creating the user interface layout used to be a snap.

It seemsl ike these days, just creating the user interface for developing web applications is a huge pain in the butt. Just trying to get your text entry fields and widgets to go where they are supposed to is extremely painful, and requires you to know JavaScript, CSS, jQuery, HTML, etc. There *has* to be an easier way to develop data entry forms that produce the needed, underlying code for a webpage.

Am I just not looking in the right place? It seems like there *must* be some kind of WYSIWYG GUI development tools out there for developing data-entry forms.

Can anyone give me some good suggestions?

Comment: this belongs on our sister site, Stack Overflow.  it will be migrated shortly.

Comment: this belongs on our sister site, Programmers StackExchange. It should be migrated shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most web frameworks handle form generation for you. If yours doesn't then there are easily a dozen others that you can pick up for no money.

Comment: The one I use is Django, but there are others out there.

Comment: Django, Ruby On Rails, CodeIgniter does some of the work for you.  Google Web Toolkit allows you to express HTML forms in pure Java.  There are a plethora of HTML form builders for Perl.  But not many of these are WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 2):

C# used with ASP.NET is strong in this area, but there is a learning curve to overcome. You can get the free versions by downloading the latest Visual Studio Express from Microsoft. The catch is that you are stuck with Windows for development, for better or worse. Visual Studio only runs on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/).  That's about the best WYSIWYG you're going to find.

Comment: That's hardly specific for that task which means it's probably just very confusing to use. A web authoring tool is probably on the other end of unusable compared with a simple text editor.

Comment: For developing simple HTML forms, it is very easy.  Drag and drop, WYSIWYG editor with a huge community backing it.  It can also integrate with PHP, if that happens to be available.  I doubt you'll find any purpose-specific form editor with the power/flexibility/following Dreamweaver has.

Comment: (I should probably note... I never use anything but VIM to edit HTML files.  heh)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sencha.com/ Ext JS is a Cross-browser JavaScript framework for rich web apps.

it also has a gui to create the interfaces.  That gui app is not free.